# Python - create SQL table syntax reading csv file in python

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, csv

Need a script that generates a .SQL file with create table syntax reading CSV file.

Table name, column name and length is provided in CSV file.

Example:

```
TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE,DATA_LENGTH
xyz          name       varchar   250
xyz          name       varchar   250
pqr          age         int
```

I have a 260 tables in my CSV file to read and convert that as create table syntax.

Comment: What have you tried so far, beyond asking someone else to write it for you?

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
csv_path = 'C:\\path_to_your_csv_file'

tables = {}
is_first_row = True

with open(csv_path) as f:
    for line in f:
        if is_first_row:
            is_first_row = False
            continue
        table_name, column_name, data_spec = [str(e).rstrip() for e in line.split(',', maxsplit=2)]
        if table_name not in tables.keys():
            tables[table_name] = []
        data_type = data_spec if ',' not in data_spec else '('.join(data_spec.split(',')) + ')'
        tables[table_name].append(column_name + ' ' + data_type)

result='\n'.join(['CREATE TABLE ' + table_name + ' (' + (', '.join(tables[table_name])) + ');' for table_name in tables.keys()])

print(result)
```

Output:

```
CREATE TABLE pqr (age int);
CREATE TABLE xyz (name varchar(250), surname varchar(250));
```